How to create new objects under old ones?
Input data format [(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2), (...),...]:
https://pastebin.com/EiZZEeQR
The task is to find a way to create new objects under old ones according to the order in which the creation function is called. In this case, we start by creating a obj_1, then a obj_2, which will hide under the obj_1. Then the obj_3 is created, and consequently this object is hidden under the first and second objects.
Desired output data - coordinates of all lines for drawing the drawing

Part of the program that @Timeless wrote is working. But my dataset is more complex. In my case, an improved solution is needed.
obj_1 = [[0.09, 0.98, 0.13, 0.98, 0.17, 0.97, 0.2, 0.94, 0.2, 0.91, 0.17, 0.88, 0.13, 0.87, 0.09, 0.87, 0.05, 0.88, 0.02, 0.91, 0.02, 0.94, 0.05, 0.97, 0.09, 0.98]]
obj_2 = [[0.1, 0.77, 0.2, 1.07]]

def create_lines(coords):
    return unary_union(
        [
            (
                Polygon(ls) if (
                    ls := LineString(batched(coo, 2))
                ).is_ring else ls
            ) for coo in coords
        ]
    )

lines1, lines2 = map(create_lines, [obj_1, obj_2])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4, 7))

plot_line(lines2.difference(lines1), color="w", add_points=False, ax=ax)
plot_line(lines1.exterior, color="w", lw=2, add_points=False, ax=ax)

ax.set(facecolor="#242c34", xticks=[], yticks=[])

plt.show()


I would simply reverse list of objects to draw from last item to first item, etc. And when you get new item then clear screen and draw again from last to first.

You didn't add the details of your plot_line() function. Instead of drawing lines, you could draw filled polygons, using white for the outline and black as the fill color. ax.fill(xs, ys, color='black', edgecolor='white', lw=1). As mentioned, you'd need to draw in back to front order.

Below is a relatively scalable solution, that creates the actual cut shapely objects instead of using of just displaying them underneath the other.
from typing import Iterable

import shapely
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from shapely import Polygon, LineString
from shapely.plotting import plot_line, plot_polygon
from shapely.strtree import STRtree

dresva = [0.09, 0.97, 0.15, 0.88, 0.03, 0.88, 0.09, 0.97]

graviy = [0.05, 0.98, 0.07, 0.98, 0.09, 0.97, 0.1, 0.95, 0.1, 0.93, 0.09, 0.91, 0.07, 0.9, 0.05, 0.9, 0.03, 0.91, 0.02,
          0.93, 0.02, 0.95, 0.03, 0.97, 0.05, 0.98]

glina = [0.02, 0.9, 0.2, 0.98]


def grouped(iterable, n=2):
    """s -> (s0,s1,s2,...sn-1), (sn,sn+1,sn+2,...s2n-1), (s2n,s2n+1,s2n+2,...s3n-1), ..."""
    return zip(*[iter(iterable)] * n)


circle = Polygon(grouped(graviy))
triangle = Polygon(grouped(dresva))
line = LineString(grouped(glina))


def overlay(geometries: Iterable[BaseGeometry]):
    """First features will be underneath, last feature on top"""
    result = []
    s = set()
    tree = STRtree(geometries)
    for idx, current_feature in enumerate(geometries):
        s.add(idx)
        overlapping_features = tree.geometries.take(list(set(tree.query(current_feature)) - s))
        cut = current_feature.difference(unary_union(overlapping_features))
        result.append(cut)
    return result



l = [line, circle, triangle]

l_overlayed = overlay(l)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4, 7))
line2, circle2, triangle2 = l_overlayed

plot_polygon(circle2, color="w", add_points=False, ax=ax)
plot_polygon(triangle2, color="w", add_points=False, ax=ax)
plot_line(line2, color="w", lw=2, add_points=False, ax=ax)

ax.set(facecolor="#242c34", xticks=[], yticks=[])
plt.show()



is there any possibility to not categorize objects by POLYGON, MULTISTRING, LINESTRING?
Input data can be objects of any form.
But they are always of the same format - [x1, y1, x2, y2,...].
https://prnt.sc/9BCFAUqoq6uB - example

input data example - https://pastebin.com/EiZZEeQR.
desired result - https://prnt.sc/2qiQzQUtE6Kq

@BobbyLith it seems that now your question is about how to get your data into appropiate shapely objects. Is that true? If yes, then I would raise an new issue instead had that is completely different than the original question.
